# How to get the second element of an array in an array ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a set as follows:

```
verb_tag_set = Set.new ["VB", "VBD", "VBG", "VBN", "VBP", "VBZ", "MD"]
```

My tagged_text array contains the following:

```
tagged_text = [["VB", "go"], ["VBG", "going"]]
```

I am trying to get all of the elements of the second row of each array by selecting those arrays that contain an element that matches one of the items in the verb_tag_set.

```
    verb_tagged_array = tagged_text.select{|el| el[1] if verb_tag_set.include?(el[0])}
    verb_tagged_array.map{|row| row[1]}
```

Although this works, I should be able to get the array in one line.

Any ideas on how to refine this code?

NOOB with ruby so any help appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Firstly, Ruby has no concept of arrays having "rows". Also, where you have `verb_tag_set.include?(el[1])`, don't you mean `verb_tag_set.include?(el[0])` and in next line should it be `row[1]`? It would help if you would show your desired output (array).

Comment: Apologies. I made the edits. I actually wrote my tagged_text array in the wrong order. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want the following.

```
require 'set'

verb_tag_set = Set.new ["VB", "VBD", "VBG", "VBN", "VBP", "VBZ", "MD"]    
tagged_text = [["VB", "go"], ["VBG", "going"]]

tagged_text.select { |a,b| verb_tag_set.include?(a) }.map(&:last)
  #=> ["go", "going"]
```

Comment: I often feel a pity for the lack of `map_reduce` function out of the box in ruby.

Comment: I chose this answer as it was easier for me to understand at my level. Both work great.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'set'

verb_tag_set = Set.new ["VB", "VBD", "VBG", "VBN", "VBP", "VBZ", "MD"]    
tagged_text = [["VB", "go"], ["VBG", "going"]]

verb_tag_set.map(&tagged_text.to_h.method(:[])).compact
#⇒ [ "go", "going" ]
```

Here we use the `tagged_text` as a mapper function for the set, getting rid of `nil`s afterwards.